# Why can i not print the results by sorting with my new list?

Tags: python

Can't get it to sort by new_list (total score) where I print the results. How can I make it sort by the new_list because when I print the new_list it prints out correctly.

```
new_list = []
for res in results:
    varv_1 = res[1]
    varv_2 = res[2]
    varv_3 = res[3]
    total = int(varv_1) + int(varv_2) + int(varv_3)
    new_list.append(total)
new_list.sort()
print(new_list)
#Total
```

```
    print("\nResultat")
    print("**********")
    print("{:<8}{:<8}{:<8}{:<8}{:<10}{:<10}".format("Namn", "1", "2", "3", "Totalt", "Genomsnitt"))

    for result in results:
        namn = result[0]
        varv_1 = result[1]
        varv_2 = result[2]
        varv_3 = result[3]
        total = int(varv_1) + int(varv_2) + int(varv_3)
        avrg = round(total / 3 ,2)
        print(f"{namn:<8}{varv_1:<8}{varv_2:<8}{varv_3:<8}{total:<10}{avrg:<10}", end="")
        print("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list that contains both the scores and the totals, then sort it by the totals.

```
import operator

new_list = sorted([(res[0], sum(map(int, res[1:4])), *map(int, res[1:4])) for res in results], key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for namn, total, varv_1, varv_2, varv_3 in new_list:
    avrg = round(total / 3 ,2)
    print(f"{namn:<8}{varv_1:<8}{varv_2:<8}{varv_3:<8}{total:<10}{avrg:<10}")
```

Comment: This didn't work, it gives me: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'. @barmar

Comment: I've changed it to convert to int before summing.